# making consistency of data member  in the whole programme without using static keyword

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below programme i use one boolean variable named check , which is being accessed inside main function by two objects of Tst1 and Test2 . But the value of check variable is not maintained in the programme . we can use static but i want to know some  alternative way ..could anyone give me some hints on it ?
Thanks in advance .

Inside jointdeatils.h

```
#pragma once

class Jointdetails
{
public:
    Jointdetails(void);
    ~Jointdetails(void);
    bool check;


};
```

Inside jointdeatils.cpp

```
#include "Jointdetails.h"

Jointdetails::Jointdetails(void)
{
    check = false ;
}

Jointdetails::~Jointdetails(void)
{
}
```

Inside analyzer.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Jointdetails.h"
class Analyzer
{
public:
    Analyzer(void);
    Jointdetails* GetJointDetails();
    Jointdetails* m_ptheCTJointDetails;
    ~Analyzer(void);
};
```

Inside analyzer.cpp

```
#include "Analyzer.h"
#include "stddef.h"
Analyzer::Analyzer(void)
{
    m_ptheCTJointDetails = new Jointdetails();

}

Analyzer::~Analyzer(void)
{
}
Jointdetails* Analyzer::GetJointDetails()
{

    if(m_ptheCTJointDetails) 
        return m_ptheCTJointDetails;
    else
        return NULL;


}
```

Inside Test1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Analyzer.h"
class Tst1
{
public:
    Tst1(void);
    Analyzer *analyzer1 ;
public:
    ~Tst1(void);
};
```

Inside Test1.cpp

```
#include "Tst1.h"

Tst1::Tst1(void)
{
    analyzer1 = new Analyzer ;
}

Tst1::~Tst1(void)
{
}
```

Inside Test2.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Analyzer.h"
class Test2
{
public:
    Test2(void);
    Analyzer *analyzer2 ;
public:
    ~Test2(void);
};
```

Inside Test2.cpp

```
#include "Test2.h"

Test2::Test2(void)
{
    analyzer2 = new Analyzer ;
}

Test2::~Test2(void)
{
}
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include "Test2.h"
#include "Tst1.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    Tst1 *test1 = new Tst1 ; //check = false
    Test2 *test2 = new Test2 ; //check = false
    test1->analyzer1->GetJointDetails()->check = true ;
    if(test2->analyzer2->GetJointDetails()->check )
        printf("Check value is changed");
    else
        printf("Check value is not changed");
        return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: so... you're looking for a design smell?

Comment: `check` is an instance variable so each object has it's own version. Why don't you want to use `static`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Because static consume memory till the end of programme . But i want to release memory after its use .

Comment: @vivek why are you concerned about 1 byte being used until the end of the program?

Comment: @SethCarnegie There are lots of place in my programme where i want to implement this concept ..just to put my thought in this forum i have used this sample programme .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're either going to have to make check static, or JointDetails a singleton (which also uses the static keyword).

If you make check static, you are saying that all instances of JointDetails have the same check.

If you make JointDetails a singleton, then you're saying that every reference to a JointDetails object is the same object, so your Tst1 and your Test2 will both have a pointer to the same object.

I *think* the latter is what you're looking for:

Jointdetails.h

```
#pragma once

class Jointdetails
{
public:
    ~Jointdetails(void);
    bool check;

    static Jointdetails* getInstance();
private:
    Jointdetails(void);
};
```

Jointdetails.cpp

```
#include "Jointdetails.h"

Jointdetails::Jointdetails(void)
{
    check = false ;
}

Jointdetails::~Jointdetails(void)
{
}

Jointdetails* Jointdetails::getInstance() {
    static Jointdetails s_instance;
    return &s_instance;
}
```

Analyzer.cpp

```
Analyzer::Analyzer(void)
{
    m_ptheCTJointDetails = Jointdetails::getInstance();
}
```

Comment: This is a long shot from best practice in C++11. Even before that, but in particular in C++11.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience! How would you propose I fix my answer?

Comment: Singletons are generally considered an anti-pattern. They should never be used. Furthermore, your singleton implementation is broken since it’s not thread safe. Finally, raw pointers should never own memory. Use a `unique_ptr` for this, if at all. This can be done entirely without pointer though.

Comment: Is "Singletons should never be used" a fact or an opinion? Fixed the pointer problem btw.

Comment: It’s an extremely widely held opinion (and by that I mean that it’s pretty much a consensus) that singletons shouldn’t be used since they make dependency injection (and hence mocking) impossible (one of the authors of *Design Patterns* have later stated that the inclusion of that pattern was an error). Personally, I wouldn’t go quite as far but I wouldn’t *recommend* using it.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possible ways to do so:

1. Use `static` storage data
2. Pass automatic or dynamic storage data as parameters to destination functions/ctors

Way #1 is more handy as you can access such data directly from any function. But it shall be considered as bad design because it almost the same thing as evil global variables.

Way #2 is more correct (see answer by [justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191596/justin) for example) but could be a bit irritating - you will need to pass required data as parameter to each required function and/or store data as class data member. Not a pleasant work in case of many classes/nested calls.

Nevertheless, if you don't care on drawbacks of way #1 consider **singleton-on-demand** concept. It allows to use static data in more dynamic way - create on demand, share access by several users and destroy when nobody use it anymore. See example (several details, includes etc skipped for brevity):

JointDetails.h

```
 class JointDetails
 {
    // Actual class definition
    // ...
 public:

    // Function accessing to JointDetails instance
    static std::shared_ptr<JointDetails> Get();
 };
```

JointDetails.cpp

```
 std::shared_ptr<JointDetails> JointDetails::Get()
 {
    static std::weak_ptr<JointDetails> s_trackInstance;
    if(s_trackInstance.expired())
    {
       auto instance = std::make_shared<JointDetails>();
       s_trackInstance = instance;
       return instance;
    }

    return s_trackInstance.lock();
 }
```

Analyzer.h

```
// All instances of Analyzer share the same instance of JointDetails.
// But JointDetails instance is created dynamically only when first instance of
// Analyzer is created and destoyed when the last instance of Analyzer is destroyed.
class Analyzer
{
   std::shared_ptr<JointDetails> m_details;
public:
   Analyzer(): m_details(JointDetails::Get()) {}
   const JointDetails& GetDetails() const { return *m_details; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

0) you needn't use `new` so often.

1) you can construct your objects with the joint details as a parameter in your constructor.

To illustrate:

```
class Tst1 {
public:
  Tst1(Jointdetails& pJointdetails) : analyzer1(pJointdetails) {
  }

  Analyzer analyzer1;
public:
  ~Tst1(void);
};

int RunProgram(Jointdetails& pJointdetails) {
  Tst1(pJointdetails);
  ...
}

int main() {
  Jointdetails jointdetails;
  const int result(RunProgram(jointdetails));
  return result;
}
```